# opening another instance of powershell with a script while passing the arguments to the new instance

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

So I have two scripts, Main_Script.ps1 and Loki.ps1. I am trying to get the main script to call the Loki script in a new window while passing the variables from the main to the new window.  So far I have gotten the script to open the second script and pass the variables but am unable to open a new instance. I have been through countless other posts to no avail. Below is the code for main and Loki. The Loki Scanner can be downloaded from https://github.com/Neo23x0/Loki. The variables are Scan_Drive which is the drive I want to scan. Machine_id which is what I want to name the output. Output_dir the output directory. Resource_Drive the drive where I put Loki. If there are any questions please let me know. It functions now just not how I want and I do not know how to get there. Assistance is greatly appreciated. I will adapt the answer to run other tools simultaneously.

Main_Script.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Scan_drive,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Machine_id,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Output_dir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Resource_drive
)

$Main_ScriptSplat = @{
"Resource_drive" = $Resource_drive
"Scan_drive" = $Scan_drive
"Machine_id" = $Machine_id
"wp_dir" = $Output_dir
}
   
mkdir ${Output_dir}:\${Machine_id}\

mkdir ${Output_dir}:\${Machine_id}\AV\

Write-Host "============================="
Write-Host "=         Loki           ="
Write-Host "============================="
Write-Host ""

& "$PSScriptRoot\Loki.ps1" @Main_ScriptSplat
```

Loki.ps1

```
param(
    $Scan_drive, $Machine_id, $Output_dir, $Resource_drive

)


$loki_folder = "${Resource_drive}:\loki"
$loki_bin = "${loki_folder}\loki.exe"


Write-Host "============================="
Write-Host "=         Loki           ="
Write-Host "============================="
Write-Host ""
& "${loki_bin}" -p ${Scan_drive}: --noprocscan --dontwait --intense -l 
"${Output_dir}:\${Machine_id}\AV\${Machine_id}.${Scan_drive}.loki.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `PowerShell` executable as a subprocess and hand in and out complex objects:

```
$verbs = Get-Verb
$verbs | Get-Member # [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition]
$output = PowerShell -Command {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] $vs
    )
    $vs | Select -First 5 | Write-Output
} -Args @(,$verbs)
$output | Get-Member # [PSCustomObject]
```

Comment: So how do I adapt this to my script. This is my first powershell script so I have spent an entire day to get to where I am now. I am sorry that I am a total noob. @Carrvo

Comment: That depends on how you want to organize the code. If you want it all in one script, then replace the `-Command` script block contents with your Loki contents. If you want them as separate files you could probably do `-File` over `-Command`.

What you are asking for is an unusual circumstance. Usually one calls other PowerShell scripts directly `& C:\path\to\script.ps1` without a new instance (this is more performant too) so you may want to consider simply doing that. In fact, if you are so new, why are you trying to have a new instance in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to open the powershell in a different window so that I can run multiple tools at the same time. So an example is that I run Loki in one instance and in another instance I might run ESET or another AV.

Comment: Look into `Start-Process` then. Are you talking about `Main_Script.ps1` opening up multiple windows that it does not wait for it? Otherwise I am not convinced that the "new instance" is actually what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I want Main_Script.ps1 to open multiple windows that it does not wait for. I need to be able to pass the arguments put into Main_Script.ps1 to the scripts it opens and for those scripts to output. As it stands now I can get it to open the window and start the script but it does not output anything. The funny thing is that everything works fine when I run it as one script.

Comment: Look at `Start-Process`.

Comment: Thank you will do. I appreciate all of the assistance. I will post here what I come up with.